Make smaller golang docker image for Gitlab CI CD linting
I have golang project with go version 1.21.4 and gitlab CI/CD linting for this project.
I am using docker runner.
stages:
  - linting

lint-vet:
  stage: linting
  tags:
    - golang-linting
  image: <MY_GOLANG_IMAGE>:latest
  script:
    - go vet ./...
  allow_failure: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"

Dockerfile for CI/CD:
FROM golang:1.23.3-alpine

RUN go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@v0.27.0  &&  \
    go install honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@v0.5.1 &&  \
    go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v1.62.0

Size of this image is 963 Mb, I want to reduse it.
I tried 2-stage building.
FROM golang:1.23.3-alpine as builder

RUN go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@v0.27.0  &&  \
    go install honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@v0.5.1 &&  \
    go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v1.62.0

FROM alpine:3.18.4

RUN apk add --no-cache bash go

COPY --from=builder /go/bin/goimports /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/staticcheck /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/golangci-lint /usr/local/bin/

But I got conflict with project golang version, error from CI/CD job:
go: errors parsing go.mod:
/builds/sub_dir/golang_linting/go.mod:3: invalid go version '1.21.4': must match format 1.23

If I set golang version equal to project (and downgrade packages), I have error during image building:
FROM golang:1.21.4-alpine as builder

RUN go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@v0.24.0  &&  \
    go install honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@v0.4.0  &&  \
    go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v1.59.0

FROM alpine:3.18.4

RUN apk add --no-cache bash go=1.21.4

COPY --from=builder /go/bin/goimports /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/staticcheck /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/golangci-lint /usr/local/bin/

Error:
ERROR [golang-linter-ci-cd-smaller stage-1 2/5] RUN apk add --no-cache bash go=1.21.4
breaks: world[go=1.21.4]
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache bash go=1.21.4" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

How can I make my image smaller, maybe a different approach is needed here?

I'm unfamiliar with GitLab CI/CD but have used similar tools. Do I understand correctly that you want to push some Go module sources through a customizable pipeline (you want to explicitly run the tools by GitLab stages rather than run them every time)? If so, I think you've several options including (1) Checkout your Go Module source into the pipeline workspace; (2) Apply an image (!) containing the goimports binary to it; (2) Apply an image (!) containing staticcheck to it; ... (3) Use golang:{LATEST} to build the module; (4) copy the resulting binary into  e.g. alpine; (4) push

This gives you distinct images that you can label e.g. goimports:0.27.0. Alternaitvely, as you have already, add these binaries to a golang:{latest} base and then just assume that they're available to your workspace when you invoke e.g. goimports in its stage. This is simpler but requires that you must rebuild the image whenever either the golang:{latest} changes or you wish to use a different version of any of the tools (contained within it).

@DazWilkin thanks for your comment! You are correct, I want to push some Go module sources through a customizable pipeline. I want to build Docker image with golang and required packages, that can execute linting commands. I will try approach you described below.

There is no such package, go=1.21.4. Alpine 3.18 has go-1.20 only.
From my experience, it is extremly dangerous to use different toolchains in build and runner stages. You built the tools with 1.23, but then dip them into go-1.20 toolchain. Er-r-r.
I'd rather keep same golang image for the runner stage as well:
FROM golang:1.21.4-alpine as builder

RUN go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@v0.24.0  &&  \
    go install honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@v0.4.0  &&  \
    go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v1.59.0

FROM golang:1.21.4-alpine

COPY --from=builder /go/bin/goimports /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/staticcheck /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/golangci-lint /usr/local/bin/

The image size is 281MB, extra 59 MB compared to 222 MB of pure golang:1.21.4-alpine. Not bad, IMO. The size of the image that uses apk add go is 387MB.
